# How can I make a decorator in models.py?

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

I have a football Team class in my django Model. I made 3 methods of win, draw and lose where the `self.Points_of_the_season` will be modified accordingly ( +3 for win, +1 for draw and +0 for lose). But when I wrote those methods, I have to change the `self.Match_Played` with each call of the 3 methods. How can I make a decorator called `@play_match` which will add 1 to the concerned field?

This is the code of models.py:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    Team_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Foundation_year = models.IntegerField()
    Points_of_season = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Match_Played = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    League = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Team_name}-{self.Foundation_year}"

    @play_match
    def win(self):
        self.Points_of_season += 3

    @play_match
    def draw(self):
        self.Points_of_season += 1

    @play_match
    def lose(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other decorator. The argument to the decorator func should just be the function, then you define your subfunction inside the decorator function which will do the "decoration" before executing your function. So in this case, my decorator function is `play_match` and the which defines `add_one` which takes in the self argument so it can access the class variables. It then increments the Match_Played and then calls the function passed to the decorator.

```
class Team:
    Team_Name = ""
    Foundation_year = 0
    Points_of_season = 0
    Match_Played = 0
    League = "league"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Team_name}-{self.Foundation_year}"

    def play_match(func):
        def add_one(self):
            self.Match_Played += 1
            func(self)
        return add_one

    @play_match
    def win(self):
        self.Points_of_season += 3

    @play_match
    def draw(self):
        self.Points_of_season += 1

    @play_match
    def lose(self):
        pass

x = Team()
x.win()
print("Num matches: ", x.Match_Played)
x.draw()
print("Num matches: ", x.Match_Played)
```

outputs:

```
Num matches:  1
Num matches:  2
```

Comment: why func(self)?

Comment: @MohamedFaresBenAyed because class methods need a self argument. Just like d_kennetz says, "The argument to the decorator func should just be the function, then you define your subfunction inside the decorator function"

Comment: @MohamedFaresBenAyed did this help solve your problem? If so you should mark it as an accepted answer to the question.

Comment: done! I accepted, sorry I forgot to accept

Comment: @MohamedFaresBenAyed Glad it helped, no worries!